# When we see a potential duplicate, how should we handle it when we don't have proper privileges?

Tags: support, duplicates

When we spot a duplicate question, what is the best way to handle it?

Of course if we have a huge reputation, we can just do it, but when we don't have enough reputation we should have ways to notify peers that this question should be reviewed.

So how to proceed, do we add a tag "possible-duplicates" that could be searched for more easily? The drawback of this is that you still need enough reputation to be able to retag a question. So do you have better ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Underneath all questions there are four buttons: "link edit close flag". If you click on *flag* then a box will pop-up allowing you to enter a message for the attention the site moderators. Enter something along the lines of "Duplicate, http://link-to-other-question.com/". This will bring it to the attention of our wonderful moderators.

You may also like to add a *comment* to the question with the same information. This helps the question asker to get an answer, but also stops the community duplicating effort and answering the duplicate.

I think that adding a tag such as "possible-duplicates" should be avoided.

Comment: Also, if you have over 20 reputation you can visit [Regulator Headquarters](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators) where at least one moderator is usually sitting in there await feedback. Though flagging is still the more commonly used of the two

Comment: @MarcoCeppi It's a bad link. Could you link to the correct new room?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS fixed