# Conflicting information on how to treat duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, flagging, duplicates, new-users

When I found a duplicate question recently, I noticed some conflicting information on how new users like myself should handle such.

On [Privileges - Cast Close and Reopen Votes](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/close-questions) it says that:

> - If the question is a duplicate, post a comment with a link to the original.

However, the page [Privileges - Vote Down](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-down) says:

> - If the question is duplicate or off-topic — flag it for moderator attention.

While on [Privileges - Flag Posts](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts) there is nothing at all about flagging duplicates.

Additionally, the answer to [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/713/when-we-see-a-potential-duplicate-how-should-we-handle-it-when-we-dont-have-pr) suggests than one should in fact do both. Some clarification on what the preferred course of action is would be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially, the answer is If you have the rep to vote to close, vote to close. If you don't, flag.

Note that the [vote down privileges](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-down) are granted at 125 reputation, and the [close questions](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/close-questions) privilege is granted at 3,000 reputation.

Comment: What about a regular down-vote? Should someone with less than 3000 but more than 125 rep also vote the question down, in addition to flagging it and providing a link to the original in a comment?

Comment: Yes. Just because you gain one privilege doesn't mean you lost others.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think it would be a good idea to mention explicitly on the 'Flag Posts' page that duplicates should be flagged.